# is possible to keep session alive using NSURLConnection doing different requests?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, session, nsurlconnection, keep-alive

I am using NSRULConnection to make http request on my iphone application. All works just fine.

The problem is after logged in I need to keep the same session to get data from the server.

I read a few posts saying all I need was using the same instance of NSURLConnection and it would use the same session... if that is true, that doesn't make sense to me, cause the NSURLConnection is not mutable and there is no method to change the request since I have to access different pages.

Is there anyway simple way to keep a session using NSURLConnection.

Comment: What do you mean by "session" here?

Comment: i think the "session" here is referred as TCP session. BTw, did you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are managing sessions using cookies, there is no need to do anything special to achieve session management.[The URL loading system](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001834-157091) automatically sends any stored cookies appropriate for an NSURLRequest. unless the request specifies not to send cookies. So, your sessions should be managed automatically for you.

However, as the Apple's doc says, if someone has set the cookie-acceptance policy to reject all cookies or only accept cookies selectively, you might be in a fix (you can change the cookie acceptance policy yourself too). In such a case, you might resort to URL based session-management; in which you append a session-identifier to the URL as a parameter (You can get this identifier as a part of the successful log-in response), which can be extracted on the server-side.  This, however, is considered really bad practice.

Another way, which I have come across more often, is to get a session-identifier as part of the response for a successful log-in and include that identifier in all your subsequent requests as a parameter. Although this would require a major change in the way the server handles the sessions.